# Heroku command line "--app" extension permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, command-line, permissions, git-remote

I have remotes to two heroku apps, one for staging and one for production. I am encountering a strange permission denied error when I try to target one of the apps. For example, if I run:

```
heroku logs --app staging
```

I get back:

```
!    You do not have access to the app staging.
```

However, if I simply change the command to:

```
heroku logs --remote staging
```

it works fine. Of course this isn't a huge inconvenience, but I would like to be able to use the --app extension without permission issue. If anyone has encountered this before, or has any ideas as to why this may be, please let me know :).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo heroku logs --app staging`?

Comment: prepending the command with sudo has no effect on the result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two options use entirely different mechanisms to lookup the Heroku app by 1) git remote name 2) heroku app name.

When you say `--app staging` you are looking up an app called `staging` which you do not own, and getting a permission denied.

When you use the `--remote staging` you are looking up the app attached to your git remote called `staging` and it works.

The right way to use `--app` is with `--app your-app-name`, since `staging` is not your app.